# Is the US support for Ukraine significantly because of Biden

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine, joe-biden

Is US's position on Ukraine significantly the result of Biden himself?

On other questions, I keep reading assumptions - stated or not - that the US supports Ukraine only because Biden does.

On the most similar question, there was a lot of comments-debating about the issue. But answers to my question would not be appropriate answers to that question.

Comment: If 99% of the population supported Ukraine but the president supported Russia we'd probably still say the country supported Russia.

Comment: No certainly not only because of Biden. The whole Congress approved supporting Ukraine. The question could explore more how Biden all by himself might be able to approve the support in order to see that this cannot be true. On the other hand, my feeling is that history will attribute quite some merit to Biden in that regard. Just imagine Trump and the GOP in power in the US. The situation for Ukraine could look a bit different now if that was the case. But that's pure speculation.

Comment: Are there any steps I can take to improve the question? Should I delete it? Considering how there's an answer-in-comments that directly opposes the two given, seems leaving it locked would be the worst response (but clearly I'm no expert)

Comment: @bharring sourcing some of the places you  'keep reading assumptions' especially if it is actually stated would probably help keep this open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguably not all that much. Biden is certainly driving foreign policy, as is his role, but Congress, which has to vote on the military assistance seems firmly aboard.

[$40B appropriation bill in May 2022](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/7691/actions).

[House](https://clerk.house.gov/Votes/2022145):   368 Yes, 57 No.

[Senate](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_votes/vote1172/vote_117_2_00191.htm) : 86 Yes, 11 No.

[Continuing Appropriations and Ukraine Supplemental Appropriations Act, 2023 (September 2022)](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6833)

[Senate](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_votes/vote1172/vote_117_2_00351.htm)  : 72/25

[House](https://clerk.house.gov/Votes/2022102) : 232/195

The problem is that some of these bills go in as multi-purpose ones, not just Ukraine spending.  Which makes it somewhat hard to discern support/opposition for Ukraine spending vs. support/opposition for non-Ukraine spending, where you certainly can expect partisanship to play a role.

So, the [1.7TR spending bill in December](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/congress/house-passes-17-trillion-spending-bill-rewrites-us-election-law-sendin-rcna62608) includes 45B$ for Ukraine and its tally of votes is nowhere as clear cut as that May 2022 bill.  House: 225 to 201, Senate: 68-29.

We'll have to see what happens with the new Congress.  For example, the outcome of [H.Res.113 - Ukraine Fatigue Resolution](https://www.congress.gov/bill/118th-congress/house-resolution/113) tabled by [Gaetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Gaetz) in February 2023.

The outcome could certainly have been different if Biden's illustrious predecessor had been in place.  Though different in what way is unclear, with [stupidity reportedly being a strong contender](https://www.businessinsider.com/trump-john-daly-golfer-video-putin-hitting-moscow-nuclear-threat-2022-3):

> A bystander filmed Daly, who took the call while enjoying food and drinks inside the Newport Beach Country Club.
>
> "You know, he was a friend of mine," Trump continued. "I got along great with him. I say, 'Vladimir, if you do it, we're hitting Moscow. I said, 'We're gonna hit Moscow.'"

[Or...](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/mar/07/donald-trump-russia-ukraine-jets-chinese)

> In a speech to Republican donors in New Orleans, Donald Trump said the US should put the Chinese flag on F-22 jets and “bomb the shit out of Russia” in retribution for its invasion of Ukraine.

Which brings us to something else about Biden and Ukraine.  I am not saying it is a Democrat thing and that a Republican POTUS could not have risen to the occasion while supporting Ukraine.

But, by happenstance, Biden is old enough to have experienced the Cold War and real risks of nuclear escalation wrt Russia as a senior politician.  While at times he has put his foot in his mouth, for example when he said [Putin could not go on as leader after this war](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/26/1089014039/biden-says-of-putin-for-gods-sake-this-man-cannot-remain-in-power), he, for the most part has been cautious about avoiding direct NATO-on-Russia escalation.  Things like [dialing back US nuclear exercises](https://www.reuters.com/business/aerospace-defense/exclusive-us-cancels-icbm-test-due-russia-nuclear-tensions-2022-04-01/), [pooh-poohing no fly zones](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2022/03/16/zelensky-biden-no-fly-zone/), etc...

In that sense, the exact style of POTUS leadership and diplomacy being used to address this crisis might be more specific to Biden than just the general tendency to support Ukraine which might very well have happened under another administration.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a Gallup poll released February 6th, 2023](https://news.gallup.com/poll/401168/americans-back-ukrainian-goal-reclaiming-territory.aspx), a clear majority of all political persuasions in the U.S. agreed that America should continue to support Ukraine, even if it meant a prolonged conflict. Support is definitely much stronger among Democrats, but 53% of Republicans and 59% of Independents also agreed.

> The Biden administration has made support for Ukraine a cornerstone of its foreign policy. This may explain the party differences seen on this question -- with Democrats far more supportive than Republicans and independents -- though majorities of all three party groups favor Ukraine’s continuing to fight to reclaim its former territory.

Republicans and Independents are more nuanced in their support, with 47% of Republicans and 28% of the total respondents saying that the U.S. is currently doing too much to help. Support for continuing assistance to Ukraine despite the risk of long term hostilities was notably down only 1% since the same poll was conducted last August.

I don't think I would be alone in saying that anything that half of Republicans and almost 6 in 10 Independents agree to has all that much to do with Biden as an individual. I think the question here has it a bit backwards: President Biden has to have strong support for Ukraine because strong support exists not only within his own political party but the wider electorate as well. That support also most adamantly exists within the upper/middle/lower echelons of the American military, which itself would be completely aghast at not continuing to trade cheap American dollars for destroyed Russian military hardware, and doubly so if that hardware is originating from Iran or North Korea.

If anything, I think @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica has a good point, that Biden being of a generation that lived through the Cold War has possibly had a tempering effect on the exact details of support being sent. In other words, it could have had an effect so long as he wasn't sure it wouldn't cause nuclear fallout, but given such strong support there's no other reason for him to not keep the Ukrainian aid flowing since enough Republicans support it that most proposals for aid aren't going to start sinking any legislation in Congress in and of themselves.

According to [the Brookings Institute](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2023/02/23/one-year-into-the-ukraine-war-what-does-the-public-think-about-american-involvement-in-the-world/), Americans overall consider U.S./China relations more important than the Ukrainian conflict so the potential for that support to change is there, but no one can predict the future or what a positive/negative economic downturn in the U.S. could mean politically.

> When voters were asked to name the top five most important foreign policy issues facing the United States, terrorism was first with 49% mentioning the issue, immigration second with 45%, cyberattacks with 41%, drug trafficking at 41%, and climate change at 39%. It is noteworthy that these issues may be international, but they have strong implications for domestic policy as well. U.S./China relations was mentioned 27% of the time, and Russia’s invasion of Ukraine was mentioned 24% of the time. Upholding democracy globally was mentioned only 14% of the time. Americans appear to be more concerned about potential issues at home, versus wide ranging geopolitical events with not yet clear ramifications.

Comment: "... anything that [people] agree to has all that much to do with Biden as an individual." That's a rather odd sentence.  "all that much" is generally used with negative valence, such as "That sentence doesn't make all that much sense". " Biden being of a generation that lived through the Cold War" Biden is only 4 years older than Trump.

Comment: @Acccumulation I don't think Trump has all that much to do with either this question or this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is**. The political system of the United States is designed in such a way that the Presidential office is one of its major independent pillar with a lot of power. And the US President is given a lot of latitude to define what foreign policies he can prioritise (subject to other checks and balance):

> Both the president and Congress have some exclusive foreign policy powers, while others are shared or not explicitly assigned by the Constitution.
>
> These two branches of government often clash over foreign policy–making, particularly when it comes to military operations, foreign aid, and immigration.
>
> The judicial branch is limited in how much it can arbitrate constitutional disputes over foreign policy, and it is often reluctant to.

*Source*: [U.S. Foreign Policy Powers: Congress and the President](https://www.cfr.org/backgrounder/us-foreign-policy-powers-congress-and-president)

Note also that a US president is elected by popular mandate. And thus, he has considerable sway over public opinion. So if Biden didn't personally support Ukraine's position, both US public and administration support for Ukraine today would be considerably constrained. (Due to the powers the US President has to command the US military, this would be true even if the Congress wanted the President to act and he didn't want to).

(It is undeniable though that currently there is considerable support in the US - both public and politically, within both US parties - if not for supporting Ukraine, then for fighting Russia.)

Comment: That's the, also correct, flip point to both other answers.  Yes, POTUS can lead the horse to water, but it does have to be willing to drink.  Both the population and congress seem fairly supportive of Ukraine, *without which aid bills could not get passed*.  But at the same time, a POTUS that just ignored the whole thing and refused to lead on Ukraine, even with a willing congress and population, would be hard to get around.